# How do I re-enter the Dark Brotherhood Sanctuary after completing the Dark Brotherhood questline?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So, I've completed the Dark Brotherhood questline, but I neglected to retrieve the Stone of Barenziah from the Dark Brotherhood Sanctuary. Now when I try to enter the Sanctuary it just glitches in the loading screen every time. I need the stone to complete the "No Stone Unturned" quest. Is there a way I can get the stone another way? Or can I enter the Sanctuary without it glitching?

Answer (score 4):

This is a rare bug. There's no other way to get the stone (except for the console), but the bug was fixed in [version 1.9.26.0.8 of the Official Skyrim Patch](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Patch#Beta_1.9.26.0.8), which was released March 4th, 2013. So if you update, you should be able to enter the Sanctuary and retrieve the gem fine.